# how to create a do-while loop using bash?

Tags: bash, do-while

I want the Menu to run once and then ask if the user wants it to run again, if they say yes it it continues to run until they say no. I saw some examples online but im not understanding how to implement it.

```
#Menu
echo "Menu"
echo "1. Display the message that indicates when the <script> command stared"
echo "2. Dispay the message that indicates when the <script> command terminated"
echo "3. game score"
read answer

if[[ $answer == 1 ]]; then
 echo""
elif[[ $answer == 2 ]]; then
 echo""
elif [[ $answer == 3]]; then
fi

echo "Do you want to repeat this routine?(Y/N)"
read yesno
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other approach:

```
#the action functions
do_script_start() {
    echo "this is a message - start"
}
do_script_term() {
    echo "this is a message - term"
}
do_score() {
    echo "this is a game score"
}

# main 
ans=(
"Display the message that indicates when the <script> command stared"
"Dispay the message that indicates when the <script> command terminated"
"game score"
"exit menu"
)
PS3="Select what you want>"
select answer in "${ans[@]}"
do
case "$REPLY" in
    1) do_script_start ;;
    2) do_script_term ;;
    3) do_score ;;
    4) break ;;
esac
done
echo "here..."
```

Comment: By `PS3="Select what you want"` you refer to the bash internal variable PS3?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou yes, the `PS3` is used as `select` prompt.

Comment: I wanted to run the menu first, then once they selected their choice(either 1, 2, or 3) and it executed, it would ask if it wanted to run the menu again. can that be done?

Comment: @G3Spin of course. it **can** be done. And in my answer you could find every needed piece...